# C# - Storing tick data into OHLC candles : Values not getting updated randomly, multi-threading issue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I've been working on a hobby project being developed in C# + Xamarin Forms + Prism + EF Core + Sqlite, debugging in UWP app.

I've written the following code to store tick data received from broker to Sqlite.

First, the OnTick call back that receives the ticks (approx. 1 tick per sec per instrument):

```
    private void OnTick(Tick tickData)
    {
        foreach (var instrument in IntradayInstruments.Where(i => i.InstrumentToken == tickData.InstrumentToken))
        {
            instrument.UpdateIntradayCandle(tickData);
        }
    }
```

And the UpdateIntradayCandle method is:

```
    public void UpdateIntradayCandle(Tick tick)
    {
        if (LastIntradayCandle != null)
        {
            if (LastIntradayCandle.Open == 0m)
            {
                LastIntradayCandle.Open = tick.LastPrice;
            }
            if (LastIntradayCandle.High < tick.LastPrice)
            {
                LastIntradayCandle.High = tick.LastPrice;
            }
            if (LastIntradayCandle.Low == 0m)
            {
                LastIntradayCandle.Low = tick.LastPrice;
            }
            else if (LastIntradayCandle.Low > tick.LastPrice)
            {
                LastIntradayCandle.Low = tick.LastPrice;
            }
            LastIntradayCandle.Close = tick.LastPrice;
        }
    }
```

The LastIntradayCandle is a property:

```
    object _sync = new object();
    private volatile IntradayCandle _lastIntradayCandle;
    public IntradayCandle LastIntradayCandle
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _lastIntradayCandle;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                _lastIntradayCandle = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, the LastIntradayCandle is changed periodically, say, 5 minutes, and a new candle is put in place for updating, from a different thread coming from a System.Threading.Timer which is scheduled to run every 5m.

```
    public void AddNewIntradayCandle()
    {
        if (LastIntradayCandle != null)
        {
            LastIntradayCandle.IsClosed = true;
        }
        var newIntradayCandle = new IntradayCandle { Open = 0m, High = 0m, Low = 0m, Close = 0m };
        LastIntradayCandle = newIntradayCandle;
        IntradayCandles.Add(newIntradayCandle);
    }
```

Now, the problem is, I'm getting 0s in those Open, High or Low but not in Close, Open having the most number of zeroes. This is happening very randomly.

[image]

I'm thinking that if any of the Open, High, Low or Close values is getting updated, it means the tick is having a value to be grabbed, but somehow one or more assignments in UpdateIntradayCandle method are not running. **Having zeroes is a strict NO for the purpose of the app.**

I'm neither formally trained as a programmer nor an expert, but a self-learning hobbyist and definitely never attempted at multi-threading before.

So, I request you to please point me what I am doing wrong, or better still, what should I be doing to make it work.

Comment: This looks like a perfect case for reactive programming.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, I'm not too familiar with the concept. Can you please elaborate what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreading and EF Core is not compatible things. EF Core context is not a thread safe. You have to create new context for each thread. Also making your object thread safe is wasting time.

So, schematically you have to do the following and you can remove locks from your object.

```cs
private void OnTick(Tick tickData)
{
    using var ctx = new MyDbContext(...);
    foreach (var instrument in ctx.IntradayInstruments.Where(i => i.InstrumentToken == tickData.InstrumentToken))
    {
        instrument.UpdateIntradayCandle(tickData);
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Svyatoslav Danyliv, do you think the problem is with saving changes? If that is so, an entire OHLC candle should go missing from the db, not just one property with no value where it is supposed to carry one. I've used object locks thinking that the 'IntradayCandle' property will be replaced with a new instance while it is being written into with values from another thread. Btw, ef core context never threw any exceptions while saving. Its just that the property 'Open' is not getting its value.

Comment: @yoursvsr, object will be not replaced. EF context produces new entity when you materialize objects, as you do it int foreach. It can cache them in it's change tracker,  but for every new context instance it will be new objects.

Comment: Please see the AddNewIntradayCandle() method wherein I'm replacing the instance with new one every 5m from a different thread coming from a timer object.

Comment: @yoursvsr, nothing changed. You have to work with one context per thread. When you get entity from context - it belongs to this context. Looks like `IntradayCandles` is a property of the class, but it should be entity which you have requested from context.

Comment: Yes, IntradayCandles is List<IntradayCandle> and is a property of the class. New objects are created in code and added to the list for saving every 5m, after the creation and updating from the ticks. So, I apologize for being repetitive, in case the problem is with EF context, an entire OHLC candle should go missing from the db, not just one property with no value where it is supposed to carry one. Can you please throw some light?

Comment: Also, if I remove the thread locks, won't it be throwing if I run AddNewIntradayCandle() while OnTick(Tick tickData) is still writing values?

Comment: You have to understand. Loks are important if you are changing propertied which are accessed by other threads. If you just change property to save to database - do that with new object always.

Comment: No, I don't understand, LastIntradayCandle is being accessed by main thread for writing tick values [OnTick(Tick tickData)] and while it is at it, it is being replaced with another instance by another thread, ie. accessed by another thread. What am I missing?

Comment: @yoursvsr, so just before saving to the database. Attach NEW entity to just created context. If there is one thread which saves to database, you can. keep DbContext cached in thread. `var newIntradayCandle = new IntradayCandle { Open = 0m, High = 0m, Low = 0m, Close = 0m };
        LastIntradayCandle = newIntradayCandle;
        ctx.IntradayCandles.Add(newIntradayCandle);
        ctx.SaveChanges()`

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response but I had to do a lot of structural changes to the program and testing but then I got rid of the zeroes once I ensured I use the DbContext in a thread safe manner. I know "Thank you"s are discouraged but I can't resist, thank you!